# How to disable children, grandchildren... of control in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

Is simple way to disable all children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren and so on of [Control](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html) ? Using code below i can disable all children on composite. Need to loop on grandchildren, great-grandchildren etc ??

```
for(Control c: composite.getChildren()) {
    c.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to set each of them enabled/disabled.  You can have a simple static helper method:

```
public static void setEnabledRecursive(Composite composite, boolean enabled) {
    Check.notNull(composite, "composite"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    for (Control control : composite.getChildren()) {
        if (control instanceof Composite) {
            setEnabledRecursive((Composite) control, enabled);
        } else {
            control.setEnabled(enabled);
        }
    }
    composite.setEnabled(enabled);
}
```

Comment: I thought it was a more sophisticated solution, but thanks ;)

Comment: There is problem with this solution when it's time to enable things again. `setEnabledRecursive` will enable everything, but there might be controls that were disabled to start with, and that should remain disabled. The only solution to this I can think of is to store the old enabled state with `Widget.setDate` and check that when enabling.